# VPN block by nation states

Tags: vpn

If possible, how would a nation state prevent a SSH connection to a US visitor's home IP in the United States?  Assume that the visitor is not a dissident, journalist or of any particular interest to the nation state and just wants the freedom to view (not send) his messages.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just blacklist residential IP ranges. Other option is packet inspection. An SSH tunnel can be distinguieshed from standard https

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how the foreign nation state would block the connection from their country back to the US, it of course is done on the nation state side. Many foreign networks including China inspect traffic and block VPNs, SSH and other encrypted remote access connection methods by default.  They may also do geo-location blocking where they block access to large IP blocks that are registered to US companies.